# How to define an activity as launcher using react-native-navigation-v1 Wix library

Tags: react-native, launcher, react-native-navigation

I've added react-native-navigation-v1 Wix library to my project. When I put bottom menu for my app as follow, it works. But when I use 'registerAppLaunchedListener' command to launch a plane activity without bottom menu the IDE cannot recognize the command (When I run my application, I just see a white page). I used this command for Wix navigation-v2 before and it worked. but now I have to use v1 because I want my app to support api16  and higher. Does it mean that I am using a wrong command in v1 or there is some problem in my library installation?

```
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation'
import Screen1 from './my_screens/Screen1'
import Screen2 from './my_screens/Screen2'

Navigation.registerComponent('my.Screen1',()=> Screen1);
Navigation.registerComponent('my.Screen2',()=> Screen2);

Navigation.startTabBasedApp({tabs:[
        {label:'One',
            screen: 'my.Screen1',
            icon: require('./my_resources/img/tools.png'),
            selectedIcon: require('./my_resources/img/tools.png'),
            title:'Screen1' },
        {label:'Two',
            screen: 'my.Screen2',
            icon: require('./my_resources/img/tools.png'),
            selectedIcon: require('./my_resources/img/tools.png'),
            title:'Screen2' },

    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix it:

```
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation'
import Screen1 from './my_screens/Screen1'
import Screen2 from './my_screens/Screen2'

Navigation.registerComponent('my.Screen1',()=> Screen1);
Navigation.registerComponent('my.Screen2',()=> Screen2);


Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({screen: {
    screen: 'my.Screen1',
    }});
```